# css3 appearance property for IE

Tags: css, appearance

I have a problem with the css3 appearance property in IE. I need it to hide a select menu's arrow, but it's just not working. I tried PIE.htc, ie-css3.htc and other IE CSS3 supporters, but none of them work with appearance. Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you hide the select menu's arrow in other browsers?

Comment: I didn't. I had to hide the whole select menu.

Answer (score 37):

```
.listing select{
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: url("../images/select-bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";

}
.listing select::-ms-expand{
    display: none;
}
```

**Note** : For Chrome, Mozilla & IE 10 Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

appearance property is no longer supported. 
If required you can use moz-appearance for firefox or 
-webkit-appearance for chrome