# Writing css code to support IE6/IE7/IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm using the following css code in my web page:

```
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;        /* Firefox */
-webkit-appearance: none;    /* Safari and Chrome */
```

Does these codes support `IE6 / IE7 / IE8`? if not, then is there any alternate code that can work in `IE6/IE7/IE8`?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp) the IE is not supporting `appearance`.

> The appearance property is not supported in any of the major browsers.
>   Firefox supports an alternative, the -moz-appearance property.
>   Safari and Chrome support an alternative, the -webkit-appearance
>   property

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088925/css3-appearance-property-for-ie) helps. But why you try to support so old browser versions?

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work in IE7/IE8, I'm a linux guy, so I don't have much idea about IE. There are lot of users who still use windows XP and IE7, so I want support to be extended to such users

Comment: The actual version of IE is Version 11.

Comment: What about users using windows XP?

Comment: WindowsXP is not longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/04/08/windows-xp-usage.aspx) there are on 17% that uses windowXP.

Comment: Isn't 17% a big number? That would constitute at least `200 million` users.

Comment: But how many will it be after the launch and free update of Win10?

Comment: After the launch and free update of Win10, that number might decrease to `100 milion` users which is still a big number